# Swift: opening another app from a custom keyboard and go back

Tags: swift, custom-keyboard

I am working on a custom keyboard. I need it to open its containing app, start recording and go back to the keyboard. I know it's possible because SwiftKey by Microsoft is doing exactly that when you tap their own dictation button, see video attached.

I was able to open the containing app, not sure how to go back to the keyboard's host app. I don't even know if that is what SwiftKey is doing, or there is some workaround.

I researched enough to be quite sure I cannot tell which app opened my containing app, and thus I can't tell what the keyboard's host app is and anyway can't have all the urls in the world.

I would love any idea, thanks a lot.

[image]